# APK dex file Encryption

Tags: java, encryption, apk, dex, apktool

How can I amend an Apk DEX file?

Steps

1. Decompile an original signed Apk file into archive file(including Smali DEX file, rescources, assets, lib etc)
2. Seperate the original DEX file apart from other original Apk files(resources, lib, assets etc)
3. Encrypt the original DEX file using AES method
4. Combine the original DEX file(already being encrypted in Step 3) with another DEX file sometimes called SHELL which has Decryption Function to decrypt the original DEX file when run in Dalvik virtual machine
5. Final step sign the Apk file again with release keystore to form a signed APK file and let users download

I am interested in learning the principle and skill to execute this process and how the Antivirus Database detect those content in the APK file

Comment: Your question is very broad. I would try to understand how existing APK protection systems work: search for protected non-malicious APKs, reverse them and try to understand how they work.

Comment: Thanks Dear Robert. Yup it is broad ,but interesting

Comment: The may be Stackoverflow is the wrong place, because this is a Q&A site which means you need to have a focused question to get good answers.

Comment: Dear Robert after your suggestion I think i am little bit clear what i try to learn 
I would like to learn Android app hardening, do you have any platform recommended
Thanks